# How to use PrimeVue with Vue 3 and ES6 import map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs3, primevue

I want to use PrimeVue as a ES6 import map. But not sure how that would look.

What I have so far.

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "primevue": "https://unpkg.com/primevue/core/core.min.js"
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
 import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';

 const LeftPanel = createApp({

 }).use(PrimeVue).mount("#left-panel");
</script>
```

Comment: have a look at [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap#mapping_path_prefixes)

Comment: @JaromandaX that doesn't work because cdn doesn't end in /

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that - didn't read it properly :p